# Importing Go Projects in IntelliJ Not Working

Tags: go, intellij-idea

I recently started out with Go programming and I wanted to checkout some open source projects. I cloned one and I wanted to get that imported into IntelliJ Community Edition 2017.1.1 but when I imported the whole project, I get strange errors. Somehow IntelliJ is not able to find the Go binaries.

Here are my settings:

```
joe-MacBook-Pro:go-ethereum joe$ echo $GOPATH
/Users/joe/Projects/Private/go-projects
joe-MacBook-Pro:go-ethereum joe$
```

Here is where Go is installed:

```
joe-MacBook-Pro:go-ethereum joe$ which go
/usr/local/bin/go
joe-MacBook-Pro:go-ethereum joe$
```

What else should I do? I'm using the Go Lang Plugin for IntelliJ version 0.171.1931

Is there anything else I should do to get this working? Here is the screenshot of the errors that I get!

[image]

Comment: As a small FYI, JetBrains has a full Go dedicated IDE: https://www.jetbrains.com/go/ you might want to check out as it's miles better than the plugin you are using (which hasn't been updated in more than a year now).

Comment: I find VS Code with the Go plugin very good at its job, just do not enable megacheck on file save (use the simpler go fmt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will answer your question:

> Please specify a path to Go SDK in Settings/Languages &
>   Frameworks/Go/Go SDK See
>   https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/wiki/Documentation#setting-up-the-go-sdk

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207004125--No-Go-SDK-defined-for-this-project-getting-this-message-in-WebStorm

Comment: Cool! Thanks and that was it!